# Problem with "csrutil enable --without debug" on Sierra

Tags: macos, applications, command-line, startup, sip

I am using a Mac on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

I want to run the app XtraFinder which opens some additional features in Finder. I used to have it on different computer, but when I download it on this one I got this error:

[image]

So I followed this [link](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/sip.html).

When I run the `csrutil enable --without debug` command I got the error: "unknown command *without*".

Is it something that I do wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure to type the entire command as it is shown? Remember to include "csrutil enable" and two dashes before "without debug"

Comment: Can you `csrutil` to show status before you enable it? Can you disable entirely and then check status? (All while still booted to the recovery OS)

Answer (score 1):

You need to partially disable System Integrity Protection. I do not encourage you to disable System Integrity Protection. It makes your computer less safe.

**How to partially disable System Integrity Protection**

1. Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> keys at startup
2. Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu
3. Enter the following command: `csrutil enable --without debug`
4. Reboot your computer

Comment: Well, I did those steps as I said in my OP. The problem is in the error: "unknown command without" (as I also said in my OP).

Comment: Don’t you need to first `csrutil -disable` to turn off all SIP and then selectively re-enable? Been a while since I have run without full sip.....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see (on High Sierra), it is the way "csrutil" works. If you invoke it like `csrutil enable --without debug` *when not booted* into Recovery OS and if you haven't done similar thing before, it will complain about "--without". However, if you *boot* into Recovery OS, it will work as expected.

Btw, after you do this thing, `csrutil enable --without debug` (or any other supported argument for "--without") will be recognized (but won't work due to need to be executed from Recovery OS) even if not booted in Recovery OS.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who still gets installation failures even with `csrutil enable --without debug`, here's the solution:

1. Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the `cmd` and `r` keys at startup
2. Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu
3. Enter the following command: `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot your computer
5. Install XtraFinder by clicking the installer
6. Repeat steps 1+2, enter: `csrutil clear`, reboot.

Step 3 completely disables your system integration protection. This should be no problem if you immediately put it back on place by the last step (step 6).

Answer (score 0):

For me, neither `csrutil enable --without debug` nor `csrutil disable` works, even after carefully implementing all the needed steps as described above. xtrafinder will only work *while* SIP is *completely* disabled. Any further thoughts?